# Use Spring entity instead of using Beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, entity, javabeans

i am using Spring MVC, i have a form to populate using a model Attribute.
I used Entity as object but also it works if i use beans or a simple class that contains all the fields of this object.
I want to know if it is a good practice to use entity as Model Attribute instead of using Beans ?

Thanks for answering  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use simple beans and then map them to the entity beans. This enables loose coupling between your controllers and data access object. Also you might not want to expose all of the data(sensitive data such as passwords) to UI layer. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, now i see the real difference